# Experiencing slow data fetching in react native with firebase: how to optimize performance

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I've built a small mobile app using React Native (Expo) with Firebase. The app allows users to view their portfolio, transactions, PNL, etc. However, I'm facing an issue where fetching data from the database is taking an excessive amount of time.

```
const Home = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const userId = route.params?.userId;
  const [clientData, setClientData] = useState(null);
  const [latestAnnouncement, setLatestAnnouncement] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userId) {
      console.error("No user ID provided");
      return;
    }

    const fetchData = async () => {

    
      const startTimeClientData = Date.now();
      const clientRef = doc(FIRESTORE_DB, "clients", userId);
      const depositsRef = collection(clientRef, "deposits");
      const withdrawalsRef = collection(clientRef, "withdrawals");
      const dataPNLRef = query(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, "dataPNL"), orderBy("date", "desc"), limit(4));
    
      const [clientDoc, depositsSnapshot, withdrawalsSnapshot, dataPNLSnapshot] = await Promise.all([
        getDoc(clientRef),
        getDocs(depositsRef),
        getDocs(withdrawalsRef),
        getDocs(dataPNLRef),
      ]);
      console.log("Fetching client data:", Date.now() - startTimeClientData, "s");
    

      const dataPNL = dataPNLSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      const latestValue = dataPNL?.[0]?.value || 0;
      const initialDeposit = clientDoc.data().initialDeposit || 0;
      const totalDeposits = depositsSnapshot.docs.reduce((sum, doc) => sum + (doc.data().value || 0), 0);
      const totalWithdrawals = withdrawalsSnapshot.docs.reduce((sum, doc) => sum + (doc.data().value || 0), 0);
      let initialBalance = initialDeposit + totalDeposits - totalWithdrawals;
      if (totalDeposits === 0 && totalWithdrawals === 0) {
        initialBalance = initialDeposit;
      }
      const finalBalance = (Math.round(initialBalance * (1 + latestValue / 100) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
      const latestWithdrawal = withdrawalsSnapshot.docs[0]?.data()?.value || 0;
      const latestDeposit = depositsSnapshot.docs[0]?.data()?.value || 0;
      const monthlyPnL = dataPNL ? dataPNL.reduce((sum, data) => sum + (data?.value || 0), 0) : 0;

      setClientData({
        currentBalance: finalBalance,
        latestWithdrawal,
        latestDeposit,
        latestValue,
        monthlyPnL
      });
      const announcementsRef = collection(FIRESTORE_DB, "announcements");
      const latestAnnouncementRef = query(announcementsRef, orderBy("date", "desc"), limit(1));
      const latestAnnouncementSnapshot = await getDocs(latestAnnouncementRef);
    
      setLatestAnnouncement(latestAnnouncementSnapshot.docs[0]?.data());
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [userId]);
```

**My observations:**

The initial read takes around 7 seconds, while subsequent reads take 1-2 seconds

**What I have tried:**

- Fetching them separately using multiple async functions takes even
  longer. The time taken seems to be volatile and inconsistent.

Here's an example of the time logs:

LOG Fetching client data: 3030 ms
LOG Fetching deposits: 827 ms
LOG Fetching withdrawals: 2009 ms
LOG Fetching dataPNL: 1168 ms
LOG Fetching latest announcement: 158 ms
Fetching Client Data: The client data was retrieved from the collection containing information about individual clients.

Fetching Deposits: The deposits sub-collection, containing values and dates for each client, was fetched next.

Fetching Withdrawals: The withdrawal sub-collection was then fetched, containing the values and dates for each client's withdrawals.

Fetching DataPNL: The dataPNL collection, which includes weekly data on percentage and dates.

- I have also tried adding indexing for the collections in the Firebase
  index option, but it didn't make a significant difference.
- I also tried converting the fetching and managing it on the server
  side using cloud functions and then calling the function's url from
  the frontend but it also didn't help.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, I added a code snippet for that purpose

Comment: Thanks for that. The next step would be to measure where the time is going. So put logging on pretty much each line, and see which one takes the most time. Or you could [use a profiler](https://reactnative.dev/docs/profiling) for that, of course - although likely most of the time will be going to one or more of the asynchronous calls to the database.

Comment: Hi, I did and fetching the latest announcement which is a collection containing only 1 document is taking 2-3 seconds. I don't know why? I tried searching for online solutions but this seems to require an in-depth knowledge. I edited the code snippet to include the changes made

Comment: For the first read from Firestore that the application performs, that seems a bit slow but not unreasonable. Subsequent reads should be a lot faster, as it no longer has to load the SDK and its dependencies.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I was banned to post more questions, I edited the question with more logs and stuff I already tried. but still nothing worked.. Thanks anyways for your guidance and insight.